# Purely discrete spectrum of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-adjoint-operators

Let $(h,D(h))$ be a self-adjoint operator on the infinite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathfrak{h}$ that is bounded below and also assume that tr$_{\mathfrak{h}}(e^{-h})<\infty$.

How can I see that $h$ has purely discrete spectrum and that the sequence of eigenvalues $e_0\leq e_1\leq e_2\leq...$ repeated according to multiplicity is unbounded? And moreover why is tr$_{\mathfrak{h}}(e^{-\beta(h-\mu)})<\infty$ for $\beta>0$ and $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What do you mean by trace here? The usual notion of just summing up the diagonal entries?

Comment: In my lecture we defined the trace of an operator h as $\sum_\alpha \langle u_\alpha, hu_\alpha\rangle$, where $\{u_\alpha\}$ is an ONB of the Hilbert space

Comment: Okay that makes sense. In that case.. A heuristic for the eigenvalues being unbounded is that if they were not (imagining that $h$ were diagonalized), they would have an upper bound and thus $e^{-h}$ would be bounded below by some $\varepsilon > 0$ on the diagonal. You'd then get a divergent trace. The last question follows from the primary since $\beta h$ commutes with $\beta \mu$ so you can break the exponent up and then you just pick up a multiplicative factor for the trace. I'd fill in details but I'm about to head out. Hopefully you can draw some ideas from this though.